how to get mean average precision values generated by lgbmranker
I use lgbmranker for my model prediction. I use mean average precision metric and lambdarank. My code is below:
gbm = lgb.LGBMRanker(objective='lambdarank',
    metric= 'map',
    boosting_type= 'gbdt',
    learning_rate= 0.05,
    min_data_in_bin=1,
    min_data_in_leaf=2,
    min_child_samples= 2,
    n_estimators= 100,
    max_bin=15,
    num_leaves=3,         # Control complexity and features used
    max_depth=3,           # Limit the depth of trees
)
# Fit the model using only the training set
gbm.fit(X_train, y_train, group=query_train, 
        eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)], eval_group=[query_test], 
        eval_at=[2,4])

how do I get mean average precision values generated by the model?
There might be a way of getting the values since the model has a metric setting in hyperparameters. Is there a way?
